# When is the features independent in order to use NB classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian, naivebayes

I am working with classification models and as I am new to it I have a question. It is said that Naive Bayes performs well when features are independent of each other. How do I know if features in my feature set are independent? Any example? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

#### Independence of Features

In most cases people want to check whether one feature is highly correlated with another (or even repeated), so that one of those can be omitted. A correlation of 1 means, that you don't lose any information if the one of the correlated features is omitted. There are multiple ways to check correlation, e.g. in Python `np.corrcoef`, `pd.DataFrame.corr` and `scipy.stats.pearsonr`.

But things can be more complicated.
Features are independent of each other if you cant use features `x_1, ..., x_n` to predict feature `x_n+1`. In most cases one might check if features are linear dependent of each other, meaning:

```
x_n+1 = a_1 * x_1 + ... + a_n * x_n + error
```

If this is the case (and the error contribution is small) one might neglect the dependent feature. Note that you can therefore omit any of all `n+1`-features, since you can restructure your equation to have any of `x_i` on the lhs.
To check this one might calculate the eigenvalues and check for values close to zero.

#### Removing dependent Features

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import naive_bayes
from sklearn import model_selection
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=10, n_repeated=0, n_informative=6, n_redundant=4, n_classes=2)
    u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(X)

#display s
s
array([8.06415389e+02, 6.69591201e+02, 4.31329281e+02, 4.02622029e+02,
       2.85447317e+02, 2.53360358e+02, 4.07459972e-13, 2.55851809e-13,
       1.72445591e-13, 6.68493846e-14])
```

So basically, 4 features are redundant. So now, we can use a feature reduction technique such as Principal Component Analysis or Linear Discriminant Analysis to reduce to only 6 features.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y)
gnb = naive_bayes.GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
gnb.score(X_test, y_test)  #results in 0.7216
```

Now we reduce the features to 6.

```
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=6)
X_trafo = pca.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X_trafo, y)
gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
gnb.score(X_test, y_test) #results in 0.7216
```

Note that the values don't need to be exaclty the same.